# Cloudwatch Custom Events SQS fails to work

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-cloudwatch, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-cloudwatch-events

I am using terraform to create the queues while also creating the Cloudwatch event rules and setting one of the queues as the target for the rules.

In summary I have a single queue that is the target for 3 separate cloudwatch events. The problem is that even though the cloudwatch event rules are identical, only one of them work when created through terraform, the others end up as failed invocations in the console with no log or any sort of debuggable information. If the custom events are created from the aws console, all works well.

#### The creation of the queue in terraform

```
resource "aws_sqs_queue" "queue_cron" {
  name                       = "cron"
  visibility_timeout_seconds = 300 # 5 minutes
  delay_seconds              = 0
  message_retention_seconds  = 1800 # 30 minutes
  receive_wait_time_seconds  = 20
}
```

#### The only working block

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_rule" "eve_vendors_bot_sync" {
  name                = "vendors-bot-sync"
  schedule_expression = "rate(1 minute)"
  description         = "Notify cron queue for vendors bot sync"
  is_enabled          = true
}

resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_target" "sqs_cron_vendors_bot_sync" {
  rule      = aws_cloudwatch_event_rule.eve_vendors_bot_sync.name
  arn       = var.queue_cron_arn
  target_id = "sqsCronVendorBotSync"

  input_transformer {
    input_template = <<EOF
{
   "messageType":"cron",
   "cronType":"vendors-bot-sync"
}
EOF
  }
}
```

#### Doesn't work even though it's identical in structure to the one above.

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_rule" "eve_restos_sync" {
  name                = "restos-sync"
  schedule_expression = "rate(1 minute)"
  description         = "Notify cron queue for restos sync"
  is_enabled          = true
}

resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_target" "sqs_cron_restos_sync" {
  rule      = aws_cloudwatch_event_rule.eve_restos_sync.name
  arn       = var.queue_cron_arn
  target_id = "sqsCronRestosSync"

  input_transformer {
    input_template = <<EOF
{
   "messageType":"cron",
   "cronType":"restaurant-hours-open-close-management"
}
EOF
  }
}
```

#### Similar to the one above, does not work

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_rule" "eve_vendors_orders_sync" {
  name                = "vendors-orders-sync"
  schedule_expression = "rate(1 minute)"
  description         = "Notify cron queue for vendors orders sync"
  is_enabled          = true
}
resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_target" "target_cron_vendors_sync" {
  rule      = aws_cloudwatch_event_rule.eve_vendors_orders_sync.name
  arn       = var.queue_cron_arn
  target_id = "sqsCronVendorsOrderSync"

  input_transformer {
    input_template = <<EOF
{
   "messageType":"cron",
   "cronType":"vendors-orders-sync"
}
EOF
  }
}
```

### Answer

The missing piece in the puzzle as rightfully pointed out by @Marchin was indeed the policy that was preventing cloudwatch from sending a message to SQS.
Here is the updated config that got it working.

1. Create the queue
2. Create a policy that will allow cloudwatch the ability to sendMessages to the queue
3. Attach the policy to the queue

```
resource "aws_sqs_queue" "queue_cron" {
  name                       = "cron"
  visibility_timeout_seconds = 300 # 5 minutes
  delay_seconds              = 0
  message_retention_seconds  = 1800 # 30 minutes
  receive_wait_time_seconds  = 20
}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "policy_sqs" {
  statement {

    sid    = "AWSEvents_"
    effect = "Allow"
    actions = [
      "sqs:SendMessage",
    ]

    principals {
      type        = "Service"
      identifiers = ["events.amazonaws.com"]
    }

    resources = [aws_sqs_queue.queue_cron.arn]

  }
}

resource "aws_sqs_queue_policy" "cron_sqs_policy" {

  queue_url = aws_sqs_queue.queue_cron.id
  policy    = data.aws_iam_policy_document.policy_sqs.json

}
```

Comment: Have you setup SQS policy to giving CW events permissions to publish to the sqs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your permissions on SQS queue are missing or are incorrect. Assuming that you are creating your `queue_cron` in terraform (not shown in the question), the queue and its policy allowing CW Events sending messages to it would be:

```
data "aws_caller_identity" "current" {}

data "aws_region" "current" {}

resource "aws_sqs_queue" "queue_cron" {
  name   = "queue_cron"
}

resource "aws_sqs_queue_policy" "test" {

  queue_url = aws_sqs_queue.queue_cron.id

  policy = <<POLICY
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Id": "sqspolicy",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "First",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "${data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id}"
      },
      "Action": "sqs:*",
      "Resource": "${aws_sqs_queue.queue_cron.arn}"
    },
    {
      "Sid": "AWSEvents_",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "events.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sqs:SendMessage",
      "Resource": "${aws_sqs_queue.queue_cron.arn}",
      "Condition": {
        "ArnEquals": {
          "aws:SourceArn": "arn:aws:events:${data.aws_region.current.name}:${data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id}:rule/*"
        }
      }
    }  
  ]
}
POLICY
}
```

Comment: @Marchin I've updated the question to include the creation of the queue and I have indeed not attached any specific policies to it. I will give the above code a try but it doesn't make sense as to why 1 of the events would work while the others wouldn't, if the policy was incorrect, none of them should have worked.

Comment: @JudeFernandes That's correct. But since you haven't shown the queue creation or its policy, a possible scenario was that it was created in AWS console and set with policy for only one queue.

Comment: @Marchin it was indeed the policy, thank you so much. The entire infra was constructed purely using terraform up until the point where the events were failing which is when I tried it through the console. It's strange that one worked while the other didn't but they're all working now that the policy is attached.